# Can I enter the UK a short time before my visa expires?

Tags: visas, uk, pakistani-citizens, visa-expiration

I have a UK visa valid until the 31st of August 2017. My nationality is Pakistani. My visa type is business visa. I have been going to the UK for more than 8 years and I have never overstayed.

I plan to visit the UK from the 14th to the 19th of August. Can I do this right before my visa is due to expire?

I don't want to have any problems, and I will leave before the visa expires.

Comment: Why _would_ there be a problem? You don't seem to give any reason to expect one.

Answer (score 7):

Of course. Your visa is valid from day x to day y.  You can enter any time during this, as long as you meet the rules of the visa.

If doing so close to the end date, the officer MIGHT ask for evidence that you'll leave on time (in case you hadn't noticed the end date), but if you have this, you'll be fine.